# Dynamic menu links using menu token

Tags: routes, navigation, tokens

I'm trying to build a menu which has *term id(tid)* token in it to the views pages I have created. Menu links work when on `taxonomy/term` page but when menu links are clicked and url is changed to the *views page*, menu token can't get *term id(tid)* from that page, so menu links don't work. Basically menu structure is like this;

*Menu on taxonomy page*:

```
   views page 1 (url: /project/%1/venues) menu path: /project/[term:tid]/venues
   views page 2 (url: /project/%1/program) menu path: /project/[term:tid]/program
```

Contextual filter used: taxonomy term id from url where `%1` is term id.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your scenario correctly, have a look at the [Taxonomy Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) module.  This is what I use to create dynamic views, where the display is dependent on the menu item clicked.
(The menu passes in that value -- e.g., city name -- as an `Argument/Contextual-Filter`.)

**Taxonomy Menu:**

- Custom Menu per vocabulary.
- Uses the default taxonomy term path or custom paths.
- Integrate with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).
- Integrate with [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto): use URL/path aliases.
- Does not interfere with other menu modules.